# imports/exports using the ~ sign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I have a components folder where I am defining components like this:

```
export const ResultAlert: FunctionComponent<ResultAlertProps> = ({
  severity,
  text,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Alert className={classes.alert} severity={severity}>
      {' '}
      {text}
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

In my components folder, I have made an `index.tsx` file that says:

```
export * from './alerts/ResultAlert';
```

Now, I need a way to make imports work like this:

```
import {ResultAlert} from '~/components';
```

Currently, this gives me an error that

```
Cannot find module '~/components' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have seen this work in the past but I am not sure how. What am I missing out? Do I need to setup any framework else for this?

Comment: You probably need an alias with Next or Webpack

Comment: Apply this solution https://medium.com/react-native-zone/english-react-native-import-with-absolute-path-2fc93faca1bb